# Binding with type coercion

Tags: raku

I'm trying to use type coercion in a signature.

How can I fix the `my Chars(Str) @a := 'hello';` line to make this code work?

```
class Chars is Array {
        submethod new(Str:D $s) {
                nextwith(|$s.comb);
        }
}

use MONKEY-TYPING;
augment class Str {
    method Chars { Chars.new(self) }
}


say Chars.new("hello").raku;
say "hello".Chars.raku;

my Chars(Str) @a := 'hello';

@a.raku.say;
```

Comment: What's the error message and what exactly do you want to achieve here? Also take into account that Chars @a is an array of Chars. Chars $a would be a Chars (which is an Array)

Comment: Coercion types are NYI.  Eventually, you should be able to do `my Chars() $a …` and $a will always coerce into Chars.  But I'd just do `'hello'.Chars`, and if you're not sure if the thing will be a string, `$foo.Str.Chars`, as it's fairly straightfoward

Answer (score 5):

You haven't said what you're trying to do as a practical matter, so this answer attempts to read between the lines. It could luckily be close to what you want, or at least educational, or miles off. Either way, if you respond to this answer by commenting, and/or editing your answer, I might be able to make it more useful.

## My best guess at the sorts of things you're after

The following seems to work OK, but no warranty is implied:

```
subset Char of Str where .chars <= 1;
say Char ~~ Str;         # True

class Chars is Array[Char] { multi method new (Str:D $_) { samewith |.comb } }

my @a is Chars;

say @a.WHAT;             # Chars

@a = Chars.new: 'foo';
say @a;                  # [f o o]
say @a.elems;            # 3
say @a.of;               # Char

@a = 'buzz'.comb;
say @a;                  # [b u z z]
say @a.elems;            # 4

@a = '4', '2';
say @a;                  # [4 2]

@a[3] := '9';
say @a;                  # [4 2 (Char) 9]

@a[4] = '100';           # Type check failed in assignment to ;
                         # expected Char but got Str ("100")
use MONKEY-TYPING;
augment class Str { method Chars { Chars.new: self } }

my (Chars(Str) $a) := \'hello';
say WHAT $a;             # Str
say $a;                  # [h e l l o]
$a[1..3] = 'bar'.comb;
say $a;                  # [h b a r o]
```

- I introduced a `Char` *subset* to correspond to a single character string type constraint and used that constraint in `is Array[Char]` when declaring/defining the `Chars` *class*.
- I used `samewith`, not `nextwith`. You'll see why if you change it back and run my code.
- The type check error message is odd: "in assignment to ;".
- `my @a is Chars` is a *permanent* and *compile-time* binding of a new `Chars`, and a corresponding type constraint, to the *symbol* `@a`.

## Responding more literally to your question

> Binding with type coercion

my (Chars(Str) $a) := '1';
say $a.WHAT; # (Chars)

> I'm trying to use type coercion in a signature.

Using the word *signature* suggests either:

```
sub a (Chars(Str) $a) { $a }
say WHAT a '1'; # (Chars)
```

or, much less likely:

```
my Chars $a;
:(Chars(Str) $a) := \'hello';
```

The syntax `:(...)` specifies a standalone signature. They're rarely used and a bit of an odd duck. For example, if you bind to a standalone signature then any variables in it must exist in the immediate lexical scope in which the binding occurs. Like a routine signature, they are bound to a `Capture`. Unlike the routine signature binding that occurs when you call a routine, the compiler doesn't turn the RHS of the `:=` binding (which are the equivalent of a routine's arguments) into a `Capture` for you, so you have to do so, eg by using the `\` capture operator.

But I strongly doubt that's what you're after.

---

If you are really interested in declaring a *variable* outside a routine, then maybe use the *list* declaration syntax (even though you're only binding to one variable):

```
my (Chars(Str) $a) := \'hello';
```

The additional parens make the difference. But you still have to use binding and a capture.

And, weirdly (or maybe I'm just too sleepy?), if you try assignment, the coercion doesn't happen:

```
my (Chars(Str) $a) = \'hello';
say WHAT $a;                    # Str
```

> How can I fix the `my Chars(Str) @a := 'hello';`?

If you try it you'll see an error message like: `Coercion Foo(Bar) is insufficiently type-like to qualify a variable`.

If you bind to a signature, you must bind a `Capture`.

You're declaring a variable with an `@` sigil. That means a type constraint on its left constrains *elements* of the variable, not the overall variable itself. That is to say, a declaration like `my Chars @a;` declares an `Array[Chars]`. Given my code above that would be an `Array[Array[Char]]`, an array of arrays of single character elements. I'm pretty sure you don't mean that.